# Is nuget.exe moved or inaccessible (500 Internal Server Error)?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I've got a number of projects, configured to download NuGet.exe and restore NuGet packages, when required. I'm using a little modified NuGet.targets, which executes this script:

```
Log.LogMessage("Downloading latest version of NuGet.exe...");
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("https://nuget.org/nuget.exe", OutputFilename);
```

Everything was working well. At least during this week this code raises exception, which returns 500 Internal Server Error, and NuGet.exe can't be downloaded. At the same time, packages downloading works.

What's happening? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me from the browser. I receive a 302 to a cdn, and the file is delivered.

I tested the snippet quickly, and it works. Maybe something temporarily from your location?

Comment: HTTP status 500 confuses me... If it would be any connection issue, either status code will be different, or there will be no status code.

Comment: True, but there might be load-balancing issues going on. The direct URL gives me a 302 to a cdn, which is automatically resolved by WebClient. For me, that's https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/downloads/nuget.exe but for you it might be something different depending on your location in the world. Maybe the host you are being redirected to is broken?

Comment: If I type "https://nuget.org/nuget.exe" in browser, it also redirects me to "https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/downloads/nuget.exe". Of course, without downloading anything... At the same time, "https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/downloads/" returns a valid error => the host (and URL) isn't banned...